# Configuring line charts with remote data in Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

I am looking to render a line chart using Kendo UI. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/line-charts/remote-data-binding

It expects the json data to be directly an array like in the format (from their example):

```
[
{
    "date": "12/30/2011",
    "close": 405,
    "volume": 6414369,
    "open": 403.51,
    "high": 406.28,
    "low": 403.49,
    "symbol": "2. AAPL"
},
{
    "date": "11/30/2011",
    "close": 382.2,
    "volume": 14464710,
    "open": 381.29,
    "high": 382.276,
    "low": 378.3,
    "symbol": "2. AAPL"
}
]
```

However, I have a URL that returns the data in the following format. Note the extra object 'ranks' at the beginning which has the array:

```
{
    "ranks": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "rank": 3,
            "rankdate": "2015-05-17T00:00:00+0000",
            "student": {
                "id": 203,
                "name": "Student1",
                "currentRank": 3,
                "LastVerified": "2015-05-17T22:30:00+0000"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "rank": 4,
            "rankdate": "2015-05-16T00:00:00+0000",
            "student": {
                "id": 203,
                "name": "Student1",
                "currentRank": 3,
                "LastVerified": "2015-05-17T22:30:00+0000"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to have the datasource look inside "ranks" for the array instead of expecting it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. One can customize the schema in Kendo for the datasource using:

```
schema: {
    data: "ranks"
},
```